ArangoDB Setup with Docker Compose
I have a backend I am trying to setup in docker compose, made of two services:

An arangoDB container
A Golang API, that depends on the arangoDB container being started and seeded with the new database and collections

In the development environment, we seed the arangoDB instance with dummy data after the container is ready with a bash script.
With the given docker-compose.yml file below, starting the arangoDB container does work, but calling the startup script (which is inside the arangoDB container) to create the new database, collections, and seed the dummy data fails with the error:
# Running script within container
docker compose up -d 
docker exec -it arangodb chmod +x /mnt/start_local_arango.sh
docker exec -it arangodb /bin/sh /mnt/start_local_arango.sh

First line of script that fails:
# start_local_arango.sh
arangosh --server.username root --server.password mypassword --server.database _system

Error:
Could not connect to endpoint 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8529', database: '_system', username: 'root'
Error message: 'Unable to connect'

I have also tried running the start_local_arango.sh script from outside the container, and that still fails with the same connection error.
# Running script from outside container, still fails
docker compose up -d 
source ./db/start_local_arango.sh

So clearly, I have configured something wrong, but I just don't know what.
If I run the following from outside the container to enter the container and then run the Arango shell manually, it works no problem and connects to the instance:
docker exec -it arangodb arangosh --server.password mypassword


docker-compose.yml
services:
  api:
    build: ./api/
    container_name: go-api
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    stdin_open: true 
    depends_on:
      - arangodb
    tty: true

  arangodb:
    image: arangodb:3.12
    container_name: arangodb
    environment:
      ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypassword
      LANG: en
    ports:
      - "8529:8529"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/mnt/
    tty: true

[FAILS] If run within container: start_local_arango.sh
echo "Configuring database..."
arangosh --server.endpoint http://localhost:8529 --server.username root --server.password mypassword --javascript.execute /mnt/arango_config.js

echo "Seeding database..."
arangoimport --server.username root --server.password mypassword --server.database new_db --file /mnt/synthetic_data/synth_data.jsonl --type jsonl --collection new_coll

echo "Arangodb running locally. Access at http://localhost:8529"

[FAILS] If run outside container: start_local_arango.sh
echo "Configuring database..."
docker exec -d arangodb sh -c "arangosh --server.endpoint http://localhost:8529 --server.username root --server.password mypassword --javascript.execute /mnt/arango_config.js"

echo "Seeding database..."
docker exec -d arangodb sh -c "arangoimport --server.username root --server.password mypassword --server.database new_db --file /mnt/synthetic_data/synth_data.jsonl --type jsonl --collection new_coll"

echo "Arangodb running locally. Access at http://localhost:8529"

arango_config.js
(executed by arangosh in first line of start_local_arango.sh)
db._createDatabase("new_db");
db._useDatabase("new_db");

db._createDocumentCollection("new_coll")
db._createEdgeCollection("hasDoc")
db._collection("new_coll").ensureIndex({ name: "userId_persistent", type: "persistent", fields: ["userId"] })

